How to configure remote respository authentication in tycho-p2-extras-plugin mirror goal?
I have a private repository which I can access using HTTP basic auth. I would like to create a local mirror of that repository using the tycho-p2-extras-plugin mvn plugin. I have added the credentials in the ~/.m2/settings.xml using both the repository id and URI:
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>test-repo</id>
            <username>*********</username>
            <password>*********</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>https://test-repo-uri.com/path/to/repo</id>
            <username>*********</username>
            <password>*********</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>test-repo-uri.com</id>
            <username>*********</username>
            <password>*********</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>

This is the mirroring pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test-repo-mirror</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-repo-mirror</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <id>mirror-target-platform</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>mirror</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>
                        <repository>
                            <id>test-repo</id>
                            <url>https://test-repo-uri.com/path/to/repo/</url>
                            <layout>p2</layout>
                        </repository>
                    </source>
                    <destination>${project.build.directory}/repo-mirror</destination>
                    <followStrictOnly>true</followStrictOnly>
                    <includeOptional>false</includeOptional>
                    <includeNonGreedy>false</includeNonGreedy>
                    <latestVersionOnly>true</latestVersionOnly>
                    <includePacked>false</includePacked>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

yet no matter what I try the mirroring attempt fail with authentication error. Am I making some sort of error? Or is it not supported?

This looks correct according to the documentation (see also here). Could you please try it with Tycho 3.0.5 to check whether this is a regression of Tycho 4.x?

@howlger I have already checked several different versions all the way down to the Tycho 1.7.0 - none of them worked.I have also confirmed that tycho is able to build the product using the target platform with the same repository definition - just to make sure I haven't made some stupid error like a typo, etc.

@howlger Based on my rather limited understanding of Tycho internals I read the sources and I think that the mirror mojo is not using the RemoteAgent type which wraps the regular p2 repository manager into a org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteArtifactRepositoryManager instance, which in turn calls (indirectly) the RemoteRepositoryLoadingHelper.setPasswordForLoading() which sets the credentials for the repository based on maven settings. Based on this I think that authorization was never supported for this particular Tycho mojo.

Potentially related: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions/1431
In there the problem is that the mirror definitions in settings.xml don't affect the miror mojo. It seems that the settings are completely ignored here.

Could you please create an issue with all the things you have already found out? And also please add here a self-answer referring to the issue.
